# Safest way to recreate vertical tabbar similar to ARIA ipad app

Tags: ios, ipad, ios5

I've been looking at ideas to change the current UI of an iPad app and I've found [ARIA v11](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/aria-v11/id489782767?mt=8) to be something that looks very useful for us. Although, I'm not sure how they created the vertical tabs but from my online research I'm hearing mix messages as what to do. I'm curious what the safest way to recreate this so that I will not break any view controllers and their methods.

We support iOS >5.0

Here is a screenshot of the specific "folder tab" type I'm trying to recreate. 
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I figured it out using [this](http://www.hollance.com/2011/11/mhtabbarcontroller-a-custom-tab-bar-for-ios-5-using-the-new-container-apis/) example, this is what I came up with quickly:

[image]

Comment: How you achieved this design ?. Am developing a vertical stack like this.

Comment: How you achieved this design ?. Am developing a vertical stack like this